# how to stop DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - After cleanup

Tags: spring, hikaricp

how to stop DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - After cleanup i am using spring configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <util:properties location="classpath:metadata_database.properties" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

please help me it is filling my server console.

Comment: using tomcat server and oracle database